# How to call from Javascript a method define in Kotlin in a Kvision project

Tags: javascript, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kvision

I have a Kotlin/JS project, using Kvision (I think started from a Kvision template)
My build.gradle.kts looks like this
https://ideone.com/yOEcMF

Questions:

1. How do I call from JS code a function defined by me in Kotlin?
   Say I have this in .kt file :

   package com.zzz

   class KotlinHelper {

   ```
    fun doXXX(str: String): Int = str.length

    fun doYYY(bytes: ByteArray): String = bytes.decodeToString()
   ```

   }

   val kotlinHelper = KotlinHelper()

I want to call it from Javascript +/- like this

```
kotlinHelper.doXXX("something");
```

(the other way around I managed, meaning call from Kotlin code defined in JS - by use of "external" modifier on Kotlin class & actual implementation in JS)
Found this https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-to-kotlin-interop.html .. but still didn't managed.

2. Can you explain how this works ?
   My Kotlin code + whatever Kotlin + Kvision brings seem to get bundled & transpiled to Javascript in "main.bundle.js"
   Code also seems obfuscated & minified.. I obviously want to call method with the name that I defined it have - is this possible?
   Is the Kotlin code, that is not used - removed?

Answer (score 0):

worked like this

Call from JS

```
new KTJS_Kvision.com.xxx.yyy.KotlinHelper().doXXX("Ana")
```

KTJS_Kvision - is my project name

com.xxx.yyy.KotlinHelper is the full name of class (incl packageName)

I also have these annotations:

```
@JsExport
class KotlinHelper {
    @JsName("doXXX")
    fun doXXX(str: String): Int = str.length
...
```